# How do I reference type in protocol declared in the same header?

Tags: objective-c

I have the following construct:

```
//  WIWeatherService.h

@protocol WeatherRequestDelegate
- (void)didStartRequest:(WIWeatherRequest*)request;
- (void)didCancelRequest:(WIWeatherRequest*)request;
- (void)didReceiveResult:(WIWeatherResult*)result ForRequest:(WIWeatherRequest*)request;
- (void)request:(WIWeatherRequest*)request DidFailWithError:(NSError*) error;
@end

@interface WIWeatherRequest : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) id<WeatherRequestDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

The problem is that interface is unknown to the protocol (since it is declared later) and vice versa if I declare protocol after interface. If I move protocol declaration to a separate file , compiler would probably complain about circular dependency.

Is there any way to resolve this situation?

Comment: maybe a simple forward declaration...?

Comment: @holex forward declaration it is. Noobish question, I know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is pretty standard, it's called *forward declaration*

Add

```
@class WIWeatherRequest;
```

to the very beginning.

A forward declaration has the following meaning:
*Compiler, please, know that identifier WIWeatherRequest is a class. I will define it later*.

This is the inheritance of the C-language from the old times when compilers were able to read only 1 file at a time, and only sequentially from top to bottom (the actual reason C introduced headers. Every header is one big forward declaration).

Comment: I knew it had to be something trivial... Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also used in C++, where you use hybrid inheritance.